# Having a 5 columned row - all must take the same height

Tags: css, height, siblings

Now this is a tricky question, with the concern of not using tables or JavaScript for this task.

Basically I have a **five** columned row, one column takes any type of content that can extend the height, but the task is to make the sibling columns take up the same height as that column with fluid content.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mrg5E/

As you can see in the second row, it has bigger content inside it that takes up the height, but this breaks the siblings height too.

I've looked around proposed answers, mainly using tables or JavaScript - this is something I need to avoid this. I've also looked at hacks such as the Holy Grail, etc, but this is mainly for 2-3 columns when I have 5 columns (sometimes 4).

Is there a possible fix in CSS to match all the siblings heights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no idea what the one column with variable content's height will be, then no, you can't do this with CSS alone. You will need to either fake it, or use javascript.

If you have a fixed width layout, you could try the [faux column](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) technique. That's "faking it" with a background image that tiles vertically, giving the illusion that the columns are the same height. The example in the article uses two columns, but there is no reason you can't use it for five.

The other way is using javascript. If you are using jquery, [there is a plugin](http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/) that can help you out. The basic idea is to identify the greatest column height, then apply that height to the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `min-height` property and for cross browser solution, take a look at:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-min-height/

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mrg5E/4/)**